# Using JavaScript with arrays, color and interactivity

Tags: javascript, arrays, snap.svg, svg.js

Thank you for being willing to look at this. I'm a Newbie.

I have several arrays the values of which I would like to translate to changing the colors in a single line of dots on an HTML site. There are 144 dots and the array is 72 digits long so each value in the array would change the value of two dots. (Eventually I'd like it to actually change the value of two RGB LED's.)

I'm not sure whether to go down the .SVG/Snap route or shift through images or what. I like the idea of .SVG because the code(vectors) is very telling of the eventual arduino code. Using images would be really easy though.

This is what I have:

```html
// W=WHITE, R=RED, 0=LIGHTS OFF, T=ORANGE(TANGERINE) 
var absnolight = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]; 
var brklghonly = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
var brklght005 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]; 
var brklght010 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
var brklght015 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]; 
var brklght020 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
var brklght025 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]; 
var brklght030 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
var brklght035 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]; 
var brklght040 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
var brklght045 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]; 
var brklght050 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R.R.R.R.R.R.R.R.R.R.R.R.R,R,R,R,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
var brklght055 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]; 
var brklght060 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
var brklght065 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]; 
var brklght070 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
var brklght075 = [0,0,0,0,0,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,0,0,0,0,0]; 
var brklght080 = [0,0,0,0,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,0,0,0,0];
var brklght085 = [0,0,0,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,0,0,0]; 
var brklght090 = [0,0,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,0,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,0,0];
var brklght095 = [0,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,0]; 
var brklght100 = [R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R];
var trnlghtlft = [T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]; 
var trnlghtrgt = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,R,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T];
var trnlghtoff = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]; 
var revlght100 = [W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W];
var revlght050 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]; 
var revlght025 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
```

Thoughts? I'm not looking for someone to do this for me, I'm just stuck as to how to approach the problem generally and would appreciate any help I can get.

J.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach it using the DOM to create the dots in sequences of twos based on the value in the array.
you would iterate the array and create elements with the desired attributes in a row each value maps to only 4 different possibilities in terms of color you just create the element and set it's attributes in sequences of twos because you already have the arrays defined.A simple break statement would do the trick. You could have even simplified the creation of the arrays because all the R's are stepwise functions that increase then decrease in multiples of twos except for the cases of rows 2-5. Use mathematics with 0 < array.length < 73 to create sequences of four values desired.

Comment: Thanks! I was just looking through the SVG.js site for some insight into animation. Not being a programmer/coder it looks hard but certainly doable. I'll check out DOM.